# subprocess.Popen stdout and stderr value mismatch

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, stdio

I am trying to use Python3 `subprocess` module's `Popen` command to write a script. I am trying to get version of few installed softwares as follows.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
nginx_version, err = Popen(["nginx", "-v"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
print("Nginx Version:" + nginx_version.decode("utf-8"))
print("Stderr:" + err.decode("utf-8"))
###################OUTPUT####################
Nginx Version:
Stderr: nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

Is there any way to shift and handle STDOUT and STDERR in standard way?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this isn't correct output, with nginx writing its version number to stderr? The most obvious explanation is that Python is doing just what it should, and nginx is the sole component behaving in a surprising way.

Comment: For example: On the bash command line, what do you get from `nginx --version 2>/dev/null`? If it's empty you know stderr really is where nginx is writing to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The behavior is really strange. `nginx -v 1> /dev/null` is printing the version `nginx version: nginx/1.16.1` while `nginx -v 2> /dev/null` is printing nothing

Comment: That's not strange. It just tells you that the version is written to stderr instead of stdout. That's arguably a bug, since the version number is the intended output of a `--version` entry point, but it's completely consistent with what your Python code is doing. If you want it corrected in future versions of nginx, I'd suggest talking to its maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems very strange, the docs explicitly state

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.

I would set it up in the following way, note the use of `text=True` to avoid having to decode a bytes output.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_version(name):
    proc = Popen([name, "--version"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True)
    program_version, stderr = proc.communicate()
    exitcode = proc.returncode
    return program_version.strip(), stderr.strip(), exitcode

nginx_version, stderr, exit_code = get_version("nginx")

if exit_code == 0:
    print("Nginx Version: " + nginx_version)
else:
    print("Stderr: " + stderr)
```

Does the same mismatch occur when running the code above?

Comment: Why would this be expected to change the behavior the OP is demonstrating?